# Android Wear Google Maps

Tags: java, android, maps, wear-os

I just started using Java, seems pretty straight forward. When I make a gps app with google maps on an android device there's no issue. However, I tried to incorporate an android wear device (Currently running on a simulator). My dismiss overlay pops up after a long click, but  the map comes up blank. I'm getting the map and it's not null so I know it's there. I'm thinking I need to use the handheld location listeners but I'n not exactly sure how to point them towards each other. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.
-WD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the google maps api key setup on your android app.  You then need to make sure that the package name in the android manifest files are the same.  This is the part that hung me up for a while.  Once you do that, you should see the map render.